# Компиляция в Qt через MinGW

Tags: mingw, qt

Здравствуйте.

---

Начал читать книгу по **Qt 4**, и столкнулся с проблемой на этапе компиляции, вообще ничего не получается, а именно:
**0)** Забиваю в **Qt Creator** код из примера, сохраняю в **D: \ ... \ Hello**,  закрываю **Qt Creator**.
**1)** Запускаю **MinGW** - Открывается командная строка с настройками под **Qt**.
**2)** Прописываю путь к **.срр** - **Path D: \ ... \ Hello** 
**3)** Пишу - **qmake -project** - как раз тут то и появляется сообщение *"qmake не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом"*

Странно, если не менять путь который по умолчанию ведет в System32 и глубже, то **qmake** работает, только не понятно с какими файлами она там работает, но не суть.

Книга: **Qt4: Программирование GUI на C++** 
Авторов: Жасмин Бланшет и Марк Саммерфилд.

**PS.** Если дойти по пункта **2** и прописать **Hello.cpp** то этот **.срр**'шник запускается в **Qt Creator**, то есть консоль его видит и переходит таки в нужную директорию.

---

**Вопрос:** Как все таки правильно компилировать в **MinGW**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй пункт неправильный. Нужно перейти в директорию, в которой лежит hello.cpp, а не прописывать ее в PATH

Но QtCreator и сам умеет создавать проекты, разве нет?

Comment: В книге не написано, вот я и подумал, что это единственный способ) А как перейти в директорию в консоли? Я просто первый раз ее юзаю) **cd** так же не помогает(

Comment: cd для перехода в другой каталог в пределах одного диска. Чтобы сменить диск, нужно просто имя диска и двоеточие, например "d:", а потом второй командой "cd hello\"

Comment: Спасибо)   _

Answer (score 1):

Берёшь и складываешь qmake.exe в папку с проектом. Для справки: команда "Построить" сама собирает проект, генерирует класс с твоей формы. Нужды постоянно открывать консоль и там писать что-то нет.